# How Remove values from Session in Asp.Net

Tags: c#

I have `Session["ID"]="1,2,3,4,5"`.

How I remove a single value(2 or any) from Session?

Comment: posth what you have tried till now. Also try to reword the question so that i will be understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string using the delimiter remove the items and then join the remaining strings using the delimiter

```
        var sessionIds = Session["ID"].Split(',').ToList();
        sessionIds.Remove("1");
        sessionIds.Remove("5");
        Session["ID"] = string.Join(",", sessionIds);
```

Comment: please make the question as answered if you have got the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna remove first value, you can use;

```
var s = "1,2,3,4,5";
var result = string.Join(",", s.Split(',').Skip(1).ToList());
Console.WriteLine(result); // 2,3,4,5
```

If you wanna remove last value,

```
var s = "1,2,3,4,5";
var lastValue = s.Split(',')[s.Split(',').Length - 1];
var result = string.Join(",", s.Split(',').TakeWhile(c => !string.Equals(c, lastValue)).ToList());
Console.WriteLine(result); // 1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 0):

Its ugly, but you could try the following:

```
var numberToRemove = 3
var result = Session["ID"]
    .Replace(numberToRemove.ToString(), string.Empty)
    .Replace(",,",",")
    .Trim(',');
Session["ID"] = result;
```

or

```
var result2 = Session["ID"]
    .Split(',')
    .Where(s => s != numberToRemove.ToString())
    .Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 += "," + s2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You an use Regex for that:

```
Session["ID"] = Regex.Replace(Session["ID"], "[15],|,[15]$", string.Empty);
```

Maybe there are whitespaces after each colon:

```
Session["ID"] = Regex.Replace(Session["ID"], "\s*[15],|,\s*[15]$", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string GetID = txtID.text;
var sessionIds = Session["ID"].ToString().Split(',').ToList();
sessionIds.Remove(GetID);
Session["ID"] = string.Join(",", sessionIds);
```